# Firestore Error: db.collection is not a function in React Firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm encountering an issue with Firestore while trying to add documents to a collection in my React application using Firebase. I've set up Firebase initialization and imported Firestore correctly, but I'm consistently getting the error

> TypeError: db.collection is not a function.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"; // Add Firestore import
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "hide",
  authDomain: "hide",
  databaseURL: "hide",
  projectId: "hide",
  storageBucket: "hide",
  messagingSenderId: "hide",
  appId: "hide",
  measurementId: "hide"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db }; // Export Firestore database instance
```

```
import { db } from "./firebase";

 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const collectionRef = db.collection("users"); // Access "users" collection
      await collectionRef.add(formData); // Add form data to Firestore
      setFormData(initialFormData);
      setFormSubmitted(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFormSubmitted(false);
      }, 3000); // Clear alert after 3 seconds
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, it is out-of-date. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document